# Chrome opens PWA automatically when opening the site

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have a web application that can be installed as `PWA`. Once installed the problem appears on Android devices with Chrome.

If a user is logged out the application will redirect to an authentication service that is hosted on a separate server. Once a user has logged in the application redirect him to main page of app. `PWA` is opened automatically at this point. I don't want this.

Does anybody know a way to prevent automatically opening `PWA` when a user open a site in browser?
It was noticed on Android 8.0 with Google Chrome 74.0.3729.157.

Also if an authentication page is rendered inside iframe `PWA` is not opened automatically.

Comment: Why would you want not to use the PWA in the first place if installed as it's pretty much the same thing except it will be faster for the user? For me without further explanation this makes very little sense

Answer (score 3):

Finally I get it.

`PWA` is installed as `WebAPK` so Android open my application automatically when an auth server returns redirect to my application https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks.

A way exists to prevent that by defining a `scope` parameter in `manifest.json`. But it is not my case because all my application is in the root.

Finally I use `iframe` to render an auth page instead of redirection to auth service directly.